# liquidate undercollateralized user without third party intervention

Tags: dapps, defi, protocol, aave, compound-protocol

Im building a **simple lending-borrowing** protocol, using yield-generating and debt tokenization pattern, and for users liquidation when its position is undercollateralized, i want to liquidate part of his collateral within the protocol without third party's assistance ( because a little  bit complex since i want to keep the protocol simple).
Is there any alternative to achieve this purpose without liquidating more than i have to liquidate, and also without risking the health of the protocol either .

Answer (score 0):

Because you are designing your own protocol, it is up to you to decide then the liquidations are checked. Because your protocol is not public and not well known, only you can answer the question of how this can be achieved. In theory, there should not be any issues you designing smart contracts any way you wish.

Comment: It’s only for educational purpose im not deploying it on mainnet, and its very like aave, so what i wanna ask is how would you for example do it ?

Comment: StackExchange is a Question & Answer website and not suited tutoring or mentoring how to learn smart contract development.